# Combine list of chars into list of strings that are split by a comma

Tags: python, list

I want to convert this format:

`['1', '1', ',', 'V', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', ' ', 'F', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'n', ',', 'v', '.', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'n', '@', 'g', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'l', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', ',', '1']`

into this format:

`[11, Verna Franklin, v.franklin@gmail.com, 1]`

Comment: Just `''.join(s)`.

Comment: But the biggest question is, how did you get that list in the first place? It looks like you probably called `list(s)` on a string, or looped over `read(1)` instead of looping over lines, or had one too many nested loops in reading a CSV, etc.

Comment: The format you list as your desired result is not legal Python.  Strings would be in quotation marks, and you haven't specified whether the 11 and 1 are strings or integers.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = ['1', '1', ',', 'V', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', ' ', 'F', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'n', ',', 'v', '.', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'n', '@', 'g', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'l', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', ',', '1']
s = ''.join(s)
s.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will convert the list of characters to standard python list of integers and strings:

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = ['1', '1', ',', 'V', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', ' ', 'F', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'n', ',', 'v', '.', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'n', '@', 'g', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'l', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', ',', '1']

n = "["
for i in f"{''.join(s)}".split(','):
    if i.isnumeric():
        n += f"{i}, "
    else:
        n += f'"{i}", '
n += "]"

n = literal_eval(n)
print(n)
```

Prints:

```
[11, 'Verna Franklin', 'v.franklin@gmail.com', 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
s = ['1', '1', ',', 'V', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', ' ', 'F', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'n', ',', 'v', '.', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'n', '@', 'g', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'l', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', ',', '1']
final_s = [''.join(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(s, key=lambda x:x==',') if not a]
```

Output:

```
['11', 'Verna Franklin', 'v.franklin@gmail.com', '1']
```